# Sumarize TIMEDIFF field

Tags: mysql

How to summarize total time with this query:

```
    SELECT 
`tblproduction`.`ID`, 
`tblproduction`.`OrderID`, 
`tblproduction`.`ProductID`,
`tblproduction`.`Start`,
`tblproduction`.`End`,
(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`tblproduction`.`EndDateTime`,`tblproduction`.`StartDateTime`))) AS TotTime
FROM `tblproduction` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tblproductionlog` ON `tblproduction`.`ID` = `tblproductionlog`.`ID` 
WHERE tblproduction.OrderID = 'a'
GROUP BY `tblproduction`.`ID`
```

The Result table is:

```
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Id     | OrderID | Start   | End     | TotTime |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1      |   a     |17:17:50 |17:28:21 |631      |  
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+  
| 2      |   a     |17:34:55 |19:49:00 |8045     |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

What I want is:

```
+---------+---------+
| OrderID | TotTime | 
+---------+---------+
|   a     | 8676    |  
+---------+---------+
```

What should I change in query?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the columns that you don't need and sum up the total time, third GROUP BY the OrderID, not the ID.

```
SELECT 
    `tblproduction`.`OrderID`, 
    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`tblproduction`.`EndDateTime`,`tblproduction`.`StartDateTime`))) AS TotTime
FROM `tblproduction` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tblproductionlog` ON `tblproduction`.`ID` = `tblproductionlog`.`ID` 
WHERE tblproduction.OrderID = 'a'
GROUP BY `tblproduction`.`OrderID`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write:-

```
SELECT 
`tblproduction`.`OrderID`, 
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`tblproduction`.`EndDateTime`,`tblproduction`.`StartDateTime`))) AS TotTime
FROM `tblproduction` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tblproductionlog` ON `tblproduction`.`ID` = `tblproductionlog`.`ID` 
WHERE tblproduction.OrderID = 'a'
GROUP BY `tblproduction`.`OrderID`;
```

This can help you.

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds - have my +1 :D

Comment: I've already tried same query but i get wrong values when I manually summarize values of TotTime field.

Comment: From query I just had to remove LEFT OUTER JOIN line. Thanks to all.